# How to create bash alias on Ubunth WSL when username has space and apostrophe

Tags: bash, windows, alias, cd-command, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to create the following alias in Ubuntu WSL:

```bsh
alias windocs='cd /mnt/c/Users/Firstname L'astname/Documents/'
```

My username is unfortunately *Firstname L'astname*, including the space and apostrophe.

I've tried using backslashes:

```bsh
alias windocs='cd /mnt/c/Users/Firstname\ L\'astname/Documents/'
```

But bash still interprets the apostrophe as the end of the string, resulting in the following error:

```
-bash: .bash_aliases: line 11: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
-bash: .bash_aliases: line 12: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I've also tried encapsulating the username in double-quotation marks:

```bsh
alias windocs='cd /mnt/c/Users/"Firstname L'astname"/Documents/'
```

And I get the same error.

How can I write this alias so that it works? It's a pain having to cd all the way to the Documents folder every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Single quotes in a single-quoted string aren't escapable, but luckily, you can just use double quotes around the alias definition and then (escaped) double quotes around the directory name:

```
alias windocs="cd \"/mnt/c/Users/Firstname L'astname/Documents/\""
```

Alternatively, you could symlink that directory into your Linux home directory:

```
ln -s "/mnt/c/Users/Firstname L'astname/Documents/" ~/docs
```

And then, simply `cd docs` (or `cd ~/docs`, if you're not in your home dir) will take you there.

Comment: I didn't even think of using `ln -s`, smart!

Comment: @JoshuaO'Reilly In situations where it's impractical to use double-quotes (e.g. because there's also lots of double-quotes or $ signs or other characters that would require a lot of ugly escaping), you can end the single-quote (`'`), escape a single quote (`\'`), and then begin the single-quoting again (`'`).  i.e. `'\''`.    `alias windocs='cd /mnt/c/Users/Firstname L'\''astname/Documents/'`.  As long as there is no unescaped white-space outside of any quotes, the shell will still treat it as one argument.

Comment: Wow, there's a lot of ways to go about doing this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Well, I should have looked this up first.
I put the entire string in double-quotation marks as per this stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40491083/how-to-add-alias-with-sed-double-quotes-and-apostrophe-into-bashrc):

```bsh
alias windocs="cd /mnt/c/Users/Firstname\ L\'astname/Documents/"
```

and it works now. This is because there is no escape mechanism from single-quote strings, but there is for double quote strings (as per the other answer).

Answer (score 1):

**For Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) only**, Windows side environment variables can be mapped into `$WSLENV` environment variable in WSL side. For example, the `/mnt/c/Users/username/` in Windows side is saved as `%USERPROFILE%` environment variable.

To do this, first add the variable in Windows by running this command as administrator in Command Prompt

```
setx WSLENV USERPROFILE
```

Then add the alias in `.bashrc` (or similar files). For example,

```
alias windocs='cd $(wslpath $USERPROFILE/Documents)'
```

Here `wslpath` translates Windows style path (backward slash) to *NIX style path (forward slash). In schematics,

```
   Windows        <--->      WSL
C:\Users\username <--->  /mnt/c/Users/username
USERPROFILE       <--->  WSLENV
```

Read [Share Environment Vars between WSL and Windows](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/share-environment-vars-between-wsl-and-windows/) blog for further information.

Comment: May I ask why this is down-voted?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I don't see where you're answering the question. This is useful information, but how would you use it to make the alias that the OP is asking for?

Comment: [terdon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22222/terdon)'s solution is more in line with my current approach, but it's good to know there are other ways to do this. Thanks!